# GUI on an E-Ink display?

Tags: display, gui, eink

I'm currently working on a horticultural project with my Raspberry Pi. I have a fair amount of my project sorted out but still have a rather major part of the project to undergo which is the integration of an e-ink display to display diagnostics and measurements.

For some background, my project is quite simply 3 shelves of plants, each having it's own watering system, LED lighting and soil moisture sensor (there is also 1 thermometer located on the top shelf). The Raspberry Pi then monitors and controls the growing conditions for the plants. My aim is to attach a small (2-4 inch) e-ink display to the pre-existing setup and have it display a GUI which can show the user information like the humidity, temperature and time in a similar manner to my mockup below:

[image: E-Ink mockup]

However, I have found that there is not the same abundance of resources available for e-ink displays as there are for other displays such as LCDs.

My question is: How would I pipe my sensor data into the e-ink display and have it add graphic elements such as the percentage circle?

P.S. I saw a video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fkVBAcvbrjU&index=10&t=0s&list=LLgF700LhcjqMmwWtcsFs92Q&frags=pl%2Cwn) where they were able to have the HDMI output completely black and only the necessary information in white. I was thinking that maybe this could be done with the colours flipped. But of course, the problems come that I am unaware of how to make such a programme (is there one already available) and that surely the e-ink would have to be either HDMI or DSI Display port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this question was asked almost 3 years back. I hope that this information will be useful to you.

Firstly: 2 to 4 inches is quite small for all that info. But up to you.

Down to the nitty-gritty: You need a driver circuit to send the update to the ePaper display. The Adafruit one mentioned by @Tom in the previous post has the driving circuit and ePaper display all-in-one.

I have used an ePaper display from [Waveshare](https://www.waveshare.com/product/displays/e-paper.htm) for my project. It's a bit bigger at 6" and happily takes an 800x600 image. All that you need to do is generate a bitmap image on the pi, then run the command, and it sends it to the display.

You can see an older video of it working with the attached Pi zero [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aaZ8FRkGCO0)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since power does not seem to a problem. The Rpi touchscreen and accompanying case seems like a better option to me. But, if you still want to go e-ink, I am using this

https://www.adafruit.com/product/3335?gclid=CjwKCAjwyMfZBRAXEiwA-R3gMyv638JvFp6GcvHh5hCmNEf02OxWcaVMWaSILeiOwVhJk5-FZ3qahxoCfMoQAvD_BwE

on a current project with rpi zero, the the linking docs do a great job of getting you up and running with text and graphics, and there is a number of example projects that you can run right off the bat to showcase the features. The one I linked in pretty small, but I believe the company makes larger ones, just don't think adafruit carries them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'll have a look at that product but I agree, it may be simpler just to go for a normal display instead.